# Releasing JDBC resources

Tags: java, memory-management, jdbc, memory-leaks

My application has a memory leak resulting from my usage of JDBC.  I have verified this by looking at a visual dump of the heap and seeing thousands of instances of ResultSet and associated objects.  My question, then, is how do I appropriately manage resources used by JDBC so they can be garbage collected?  Do I need to call ".close()" for every statement that is used?  Do I need to call ".close()" on the ResultSets themselves?

How would you free the memory used by the call:

```
ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("some sql query");
```

??

I see that there are other, very similar, questions.  Apologies if this is redundant, but either I don't quite follow the answers or they don't seem to apply universally.  I am trying to achieve an authoritative answer on how to manage memory when using JDBC.

::EDIT::  Adding some code samples

I have a class that is basically a JDBC helper that I use to simplify database interactions, the main two methods are for executing an insert or update, and for executing select statements.

This one for executing insert or update statements:

```
public int executeCommand(String sqlCommand) throws SQLException {
    if (connection == null || connection.isClosed()) {
        sqlConnect();
    }
    Statement st = connection.createStatement();
    int ret = st.executeUpdate(sqlCommand);
    st.close();
    return ret;
}
```

And this one for returning ResultSets from a select:

```
public ResultSet executeSelect(String select) throws SQLException {
    if (connection == null || connection.isClosed()) {
        sqlConnect();
    }
    ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(select);
    return rs;
}
```

After using the executeSelect() method, I *always* call resultset.getStatement().close()

Examining a heap dump with object allocation tracing on shows statements still being held onto from both of those methods...

Comment: make sure you close the resultset and statement in `try { } finally` blocks and set both to null. the code that uses these should be inside the block

Comment: if you add typical jdbc execution code that you use, it might be more helpful for us to comment if you are not releasing any of your jdbc resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should close the Statement if you are not going to reuse it. It is usually good form to first close the ResultSet as some implementations did not close the ResultSet automatically (even if they should).

If you are repeating the same queries you should probably use a PreparedStatement to reduce parsing overhead. And if you add parameters to your query you really should use PreparedStatement to avoid risk of sql injection.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ResultSets and Statements should always be closed in a finally block. Using JDBC wrappers such as Spring's JdbcTemplate helps making the code less verbose and close everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

I copied this from a project I have been working on.  I am in the process of refactoring it to use Hibernate (from the code it should be clear why!!).  Using a ORM tool like Hibernate is one way to resolve your issue.  Otherwise, here is the way I used normal DAOs to access the data.  There is no memory leak in our code, so this may help as a template.  Hope it helps, memory leaks are terrible!

```
@Override
public List<CampaignsDTO> getCampaign(String key) {
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    try {
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(getSQL("CampaignsDAOImpl.getPendingCampaigns"));
        statement.setString(1, key);
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

        List<CampaignsDTO> list = new ArrayList<CampaignsDTO>();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            list.add(new CampaignsDTO(
                    resultSet.getTimestamp(resultSet.findColumn("cmp_name")), 
                    ...));
        }
        return list;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.fatal(LoggerCodes.DATABASE_ERROR, e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        close(statement);
    }
}
```

The close() method looks like this:

```
public void close(PreparedStatement statement) {
    try {
        if (statement != null && !statement.isClosed())
            statement.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.debug(LoggerCodes.TRACE, "Warning! PreparedStatement could not be closed.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should close JDBC statements when you are done. ResultSets should be released when associated statements are closed - but you can do it explicitly if you want.

You need to make sure that you also close all JDBC resources in exception cases.

Use Try-Catch-Finally block - eg:

```
try {
    conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    rs = stmet.executeQuery("select * from sometable");
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
} catch (Throwable t) {
    // do error handling
} finally {
    try {
         if (stmt != null) { 
             stmt.close();
         }
         if (conn != null) { 
             conn.close();
         }
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: This code has a problem...if stmt.close() throws a SQLException, then conn.close() will not be called.  You need to wrap stmt.close() and conn.close() with separate try/catch blocks.  All the more reason to abstract all this boilerplate code away...as mentioned elsewhere, Spring's JdbcTemplate is a good choice.